# need to vertically align a span with a input type="text"

Tags: html, css

here is the live link: http://mrgsp.md:8080/awesome/foobar
**click create** and after **save** to get **validation messages (spans)**, they are **vertically aligned a bit higher** than the text inputs

How to align them vertically the same as the text inputs ?

Answer (score 4):

Not entirely sure about how you're generating the markup on the server side, but a better way of doing the form is to use `label` - `input` pairs inside an unordered list. Make the `label`s inline blocks, give them a width, then use `vertical-align` to get their alignment centered.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><label for="name">Name: </label><input id="name" name="name" type="text" /></li>
    <li><label for="person1">Person 1: </label><input id="person1" name="person1" type="text" /></li>
    <li><label for="hobby">Hobby: </label>
        <select name="Hobby" id="hobby">
            <option value="0">not selected</option>
            <option value="1">swimming</option>
            <option value="2">gaming</option>

        </select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

li input, li select {
    padding: 3px 4px 4px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/pCCsg/ for the complete example. If you can't change the markup, this should still work for your current HTML. Just replace the `label` and `input, select` selectors with the classes you're using.

Answer (score 1):

If all items are aligned that way, assign them a class and use:

```
position: relative;
bottom: 5px; /* for example */
```